# java: enforce no arg constructor in subclass at run time

Tags: java, inheritance, reflection

I know there's [no way to enforce this at compile time](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3164343/1168364), but I was hoping there'd be a way to do this at runtime maybe using reflection.

Comment: What would that achieve? Your program errors out with a runtime exception? How is that different from what would happen if the constructor was missing and you tried to call it?

Comment: If anything, you may want to look at a custom build step (maybe triggered by an annotation) that can verify the class structure (similar to running Findbugs or unit tests during builds). http://stackoverflow.com/a/803433/14955

Comment: There's no question in this question. Presumably you want to ask how to do it?

Comment: Why? What do you care innthe base class about how derived classes are constructed? This is not a proper concern of a base class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do it the obvious way, with reflection:

```
public class Superclass {
    public Superclass() {
        try {
            // get the constructor with no arguments
            this.getClass().getConstructor();
        } catch(ReflectiveOperationException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Subclass doesn't have a no-argument constructor, or the constructor is not accessible", e);
        }
    }
}
```

(Note that `getConstructor` will only return the constructor if it is public; to allow private constructors too, use `getDeclaredConstructor`).

Comment: ReflectiveOperationException! That's new (and much appreciated).